# How do i save objects in a special order with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Good Morning,

this is my first question here, so please be gentle! ;-) If you need any more information, please tell me!

I'm using Hibernate 3.2.1 and creating a Java Batch-Application which reads a textfile, turns the records into Java-Objects and saves it to the Database. The textfile consists of many record-groups and i should only "commit" after a group of records is completely done.
I create the Objects ID with a sequence generator.

My problem is, in some cases, the order of the IDs is important - and I don't know how to influence this.

[edit]

I'll try to give an example:

```
Retourmeldung r1 = new Retourmeldung();
Retourmeldung r2 = new Retourmeldung();

r1.process();
r2.process();

getEntityManager().merge(r1);
getEntityManager().merge(r2);
        getEntityManager().flush();
```

It is necessary, that r1 has a lower ID than r2(for example: r1.getID() = 213 and r2.getID() = 214) because another programm will read the database again and the different records are meant to be in a special setting.

[/edit]

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Helene

Edit: 
Exception Stack Trace when I add

```
@Id 
@Column(name="ID",unique=true,nullable=false,precision=16) 
@GeneratedValue(generator="RETOURMELDUNG") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="RETOURMELDUNG",sequenceName="SEQ_RETOURMELDUNG") 
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)



> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'functionServiceDAO': Autowiring of fields
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private
> at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.dao.jpa.Speicherservice
> at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.dao.impl.FunctionServiceDAOImpl.speicherservice;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'speicherservice': Autowiring of fields
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
> at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.dao.jpa.Speicherservice.factory; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource [META-INF/lkfEinarbApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation
> of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
>       at at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.main.LkfEinarbVerarbeitung.<init>(LkfEinarbVerarbeitung.java:26)
>       at at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.main.LkfEinarbMain.main(LkfEinarbMain.java:20)
>     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private
> at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.dao.jpa.Speicherservice
> at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.dao.impl.FunctionServiceDAOImpl.speicherservice;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'speicherservice': Autowiring of fields
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
> at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.dao.jpa.Speicherservice.factory; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource [META-INF/lkfEinarbApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation
> of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
>       ... 15 more
>     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'speicherservice': Autowiring of fields
> failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
> at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.dao.jpa.Speicherservice.factory; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource [META-INF/lkfEinarbApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation
> of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
>       ... 17 more
>     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
> at.sozvers.svb.lkfEinarb.batch.dao.jpa.Speicherservice.factory; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource [META-INF/lkfEinarbApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation
> of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
>       ... 30 more
>     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource [META-INF/lkfEinarbApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of
> init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
>       ... 32 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.make(PropertyBinder.java:145)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindId(AnnotationBinder.java:1738)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1180)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:710)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processArtifactsOfType(AnnotationConfiguration.java:452)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:268)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1112)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1233)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:154)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:869)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:407)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:224)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
>       ... 44 more
>     Programm LkfEinarb-Batch fehlerhaftes Programmende 17-12-2013 10:11:17
```

Comment: If you give some example, it is easier to give a specific answer. In general if you have an identifying attribute, use this as a key. If you don't have that, use a sequence or something like this. The order in which you insert does not mean anything to the database, but you can sort your data when you retrieve it, so no worries there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) in this case it is important that I am able to influence which Database record has a higher ID and which one has a lower one. For Example, I create "Retourmeldung1" and "Retourmeldung2", it's necessary that Retourmeldung1 has the ID 2333455 and Retourmeldung2 has the ID 2333456. I'll try to put a little example in the Question above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider separate id generator for each entity like below.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "classname_seq_generator", sequenceName = "classname_id_seq")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "classname_seq_generator")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
Long id;
```

Comment: That sounds very good. I tried it out and got a "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException". Seems like Spring isn't able to autowire my EntityManagerFactory anymore.

Comment: @HeleneWie Please update your question with the exception stack-trace or create new question.

Comment: I've added the StackTrace to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can flush the session after merge so it is actually inserted before the second merge.

[Reference here.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)